# TensorFlow with custom gym environment: Layer "dense_6" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I am trying to use TF to solve a custom gym environment, all within Google Colab.

- The main script is the TF "DQN Tutorial" available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/docs/tutorials/1_dqn_tutorial.ipynb#scrollTo=sMitx5qSgJk1).
- In place of `env_name = "CartPole-v0"` I am using `env_name = "gym_examples/GridWorld-v0"`, where `gym_examples/GridWorld-v0` is the sample custom environment described in the gym documentation [here](https://www.gymlibrary.ml/content/environment_creation/#environment-creation). (That example uses gym v0.25.0 but TF requires gym <= v0.23.0, so I also had to tweak the rendering code a bit to make it work in v0.23.0.)

The environment loads fine via `env = suite_gym.load(env_name)`, and subsequent code cells run fine as well, until the following two cells:

```
fc_layer_params = (100, 50)
action_tensor_spec = tensor_spec.from_spec(env.action_spec())
num_actions = action_tensor_spec.maximum - action_tensor_spec.minimum + 1

# Define a helper function to create Dense layers configured with the right
# activation and kernel initializer.
def dense_layer(num_units):
  return tf.keras.layers.Dense(
      num_units,
      activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling(
          scale=2.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='truncated_normal'))

# QNetwork consists of a sequence of Dense layers followed by a dense layer
# with `num_actions` units to generate one q_value per available action as
# its output.
dense_layers = [dense_layer(num_units) for num_units in fc_layer_params]
q_values_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    num_actions,
    activation=None,
    kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(
        minval=-0.03, maxval=0.03),
    bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(-0.2))
q_net = sequential.Sequential(dense_layers + [q_values_layer])
```

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

train_step_counter = tf.Variable(0)

agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent(
    train_env.time_step_spec(),
    train_env.action_spec(),
    q_network=q_net,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter)

agent.initialize()
```

After that cell, I get an error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_2" (type Sequential).

Layer "dense_6" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[2, 2]])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[3, 2]])>]

Call arguments received by layer "sequential_2" (type Sequential):
  • inputs={'agent': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 2), dtype=int64)', 'target': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 2), dtype=int64)'}
  • network_state=()
  • kwargs={'step_type': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(1,), dtype=int32)', 'training': 'None'}
  In call to configurable 'DqnAgent' (<class 'tf_agents.agents.dqn.dqn_agent.DqnAgent'>)
```

I'm too much of a TF novice to understand what's going on here. I suspect it's because the action state changed from 2 states (in CartPole) to 4 (in the custom GridWorld environment). But beyond that I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You are going to have to show how you created your custom env

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using an [Embedding layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) as your first layer. In this example (`Embedding(16, 4)`), 16 is the grid size (4x4), and 4 is the [output dimension](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings#using_the_embedding_layer).

```py
dense_layers = [dense_layer(num_units) for num_units in fc_layer_params]
```

For example, replacing the above line with the code below will eradicate the error.

```py
    dense_layers = [
        # First layer
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(16, 4),

        # Other layers
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)
    ]
```

Source and for further explanation:
https://martin-ueding.de/posts/reinforcement-learning-with-frozen-lake/